# How to show a card in react conditionally?

Tags: reactjs

```
 const handleInputChange = event => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
    setSelectedFileName(event.target.files[0].name);
    var fileName = event.target.files[0].name;
    var uploadedFile = event.target.files[0];
    convertUploadFile(fileName, uploadedFile);
  };
```

This is my function that properly gets the name of a file that is uploaded to the system.

```
<Card>
      <InstallerWrapper>
        <Text><p>{selectedFileName}</p></Text>
      </InstallerWrapper>
</Card>
```

I have this card here that just shows up on the page, but I only want it to show up when a file is uploaded.  How would I go about this?  Any help is appreciated.

```
 const [selectedFileName, setSelectedFileName] = useState();
```

This is also defined as const in the file

Comment: Divith Rajagopal, do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://<sitename>.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2):

```
{ selectedFileName &&
  <Card>
    <InstallerWrapper>
      <Text><p>{selectedFileName}</p></Text>
    </InstallerWrapper>
  </Card>
}
```

Please read the basics on [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).